# How can last row if last row is 003

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

how do I add +1 data if the last data type varchar data is in format 001, 002, 003 , 
i try that but results is 1

```
 $nis = Profile::all()->last();
        $nisnow = $nis->nis += 1;
        dd($nisnow);
```

Edited :
my expect results if last data 003 + 1=004

Comment: what results do u expect? `001 + 1=002` ? and what's the result of $nis->profile

Comment: yes my expect result if last data 003 + 1 = 004 like that, and i'm update my code, the result of $nis->nis is 003

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP will change string to integer when you calculate, so you can use [str_pad](https://www.php.net/str_pad) to change the integer to string and fill with '0', it will keep the string with three numbers.

```php
$nisnow = $nis->profile += 1;
str_pad($nisnow, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```